# Как сделать рассылку по базе данных пользователей сайта на Django через админку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Мне необходимо добавить функционал рассылки из админ панели Django по пользователям, которые подписались на обновления сайта.

Т.е. задача следующая: необходима возможность ввода сообщения в админке и отправка по нажатию кнопки. Как или с помощью чего это можно реализовать?

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать с помощью admin action. https://habr.com/en/articles/140409/

Comment: Также советую отправку писем сделать через celery, все таки процесс довольно долгий